# Contravariant type parameter in Java?

Tags: java, c#, android, generics

I'm looking at porting this C# library to Java and Android

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/tree/master/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy.Client.DotNet

I want to port this interface

```
public interface IHandle<in T> where T : class
{
    void Handle(T message);
}
```

It needs to handle Contravariance, so that it can handle messages like `IHandle<ISomeIntefaceOrBaseClass>` etc

A user of the library can add subcribers and when a message comes in I check for a handler doing

```
subscribers
   .OfType<IHandle<T>>();
```

Is this possible with Java generics, or are there a more 'Java-way' of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I assume with `subscribers.OfType<IHandle<T>>();` you want to get all subscribers that have the type `IHandle<T>` where `T` is the type of the message, right?

In Java you'd have to change your code somewhat, since becaus of type erasure you can't provide a type like this.

Assuming you have a single handle per type/class, you could do something like this:

```
interface IHandle<T> {
   Class<T> getMessageType(); //needed to query the handle for the supported class
   void handle( T message );
}
```

For creating implementations of that interface, you'd have several options:

Create an implementation per class:

```
class SpecialMessageHandle implements IHandle<SpecialMessage> {
  public Class<SpecialMessage> getMessageType() { return SpecialMessage.class; }

  public handle( SpecialMessage message ) { ... }
}
```

Or pass the class as a parameter:

```
class Handle<T> implements IHandle<T> {
  Class<T> messageClass;

  public Handle( Class<T> msgClass ) { messageClass = msgClass; }

  public Class<T> getMessageType() { return messageClass; }

  public handle( T message ) { ... }
}
```

You'd then probably have a map message class to handle class and handle class to subscribers (e.g. a Guava Multimap):

```
Map<Class<?>, IHandle<?>> handles = ...;
Multimap<IHandle<?>, Subscriber> subscribers = ...;
```

Note that I use `Class<?>` here because I don't know whether there is a common superclass or interface for the classes. If you have a common superclass or interface `X` then you'd use `Class<? extends X>` instead.

Additionally note that I used `IHandle<?>` since in Java you can't define the map in a way that key and value need to use the same generic type while supporting different keys, i.e. you can't do `Map<Class<T>, IHandle<T>>` where each key would be a different `T` but only allows a value that fits the key.

Adding a handle would look like this:

```
handles.put( handle.getMessageType(), handle );
```

Querying that map with a message would then work like this:

```
IHandle<?> handle = handles.get( message.getClass() ); 
Collection<Subscriber> handleSubscribers = subscribers.get( handle  );
```

Note that if you want to get the subscribers for super classes as well (e.g. if `SpecialMessage extends Message` and you want to get those that subscribed for `Message` as well), then you'd need to walk up the class hierarchy.

Here's what you'd do for *one* level up:

```
handles.get( message.getClass().getSuperclass() );
for( Class<?> interface : message.getClass().getInterfaces() ) {
  handles.get( message );
}
```

Comment: Hmm there can be 0 - n handlers of a type. Cant I use Java 8 Streams somehow etc?

Comment: There is no Covariance / Contravariance built into java btw?

Comment: Did some more research, looks like Covariance is possible in Java but Contravariance is not, bummer

Comment: Hmm, I don't know whether you could use Java 8 streams in general but since Android doesn't support the new Java 8 features yet, it would not be an option anyways. For supporting 0 to n handlers you'd use a multimap as well, or if you can't use Guava, a `Map<Class<?>, Collection<IHandler<?>>` (replace `Collection` with `List` or `Set` if needed).

Comment: Can I get around the need of implementing getMessageType? I would like if it was enough for the Handlers to only Implement a handler method.

Comment: @Anders you could, it then would just not be queryable at runtime, i.e. you could get the handler from the map via the class but once you have it, you wouldn't know what message class that handler would support.